# up voting limit

Tags: support, voting, up-votes

Help says:
"You can vote 30 times per UTC day, plus 10 more times on questions only."
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up

What exactly does it mean?
Today I have up-voted 37 times. So, I would expect to be able to up-vote questions at least.

[image]

And now I am not allowed to vote for answers nor questions. Message is: "Daily vote limit reached; vote again in 16 hours"

[image]

Am I missing something? Or is there some bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s not that simple. Your total vote limit is set in a complicated way such that once you see a “you have 5 votes left” warning, this is correct. More specifically, the limit is set once you cast your 25th answer or total vote (there are conflicting reports as to which is true). So, to use up all your votes, you have to be sure to cast a given portion of your early votes on questions.

See [this post on the main Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5213/255554) for details and join the campaign to simplify the mechanism [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238680/255554).

Comment: I don't mind whatever the mechanism or calculation is. At this point I see, that problem is in help. Statement in help is misleading. And that is not good.